# Fastest way to remove date part from pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, date, time, timestamp

pandas `Timestamp` has an efficient way (i.e. `normalize()` method) to remove the time part leaving only date, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
timeStamp = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 13:15:17')
print('date only:',timeStamp.normalize())
```

Is there any efficient (i.e. more efficient than `timeStamp - timeStamp.normalize()`) way to remove the date part from a timestamp?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**: Please, the result has to be of type `pd.Timedelta`.

Comment: `timeStamp-timeStamp.normalize()`  for timedelta? or `timeStamp.time()`  for datetime.time?

Comment: `timeStamp.time()` will give you the `datetime.time`, though that can be more painful to work with than the `Timedelta`. For instance `timeStamp.time() + timeStamp` doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific: I want the result to be of type, which I can work efficiently with in DataFrames, e.g. `pd.Timedelta`.

Comment: With pandas the recommended dtypes are `datetime64` and `timedelta64`, so the subtraction is likely the best option. If you created the datetime in the first place from a time format, then perhaps use `pd.to_timedelta` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
timeStamp = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 13:15:17').time()
print(timeStamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.time()` function:

```
import pandas as pd
timeStamp = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01 13:15:17')
print('time only:',timeStamp.time())
```

output:

```
time only: 13:15:17
```